# Accesing SQLite database for Android testing

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, android-context

I'm trying to set up some Unit testing for an android application and having a hard time getting access to my database. I copy the database from the assets directory to the system during first usage. Database is set up as following:

```
private class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
        this.context = context;

        // Write a full path to the databases of your application
        openDataBase();
    }

    // This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("DB", "Delete");

            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    // Performing a database existence check
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        // Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should
        // be closed
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    // Method for copying the database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
        // The stream source is located in the assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(
                    DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the created empty database on your Android device
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Copying the database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        // Don’t forget to close the streams
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        Log.d("DB", "Open");

        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        Log.d("DB", "Close");

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("DB", "Create");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d("DB", "Update");
    }
```

I use a singleton to access it:

```
private static Database sInstance;

/**
 * Open the database
 *
 * @param context The applications context
 */
public Database(Context context) {
    DBOpenHelper openHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    database = openHelper.openDataBase();
}

public static synchronized Database getDatabase(
        Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new Database(context);
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

Now I try to access it in my AndroidTestCase

```
public class DatabaseTest extends AndroidTestCase {
Database database;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    database = Database.getDatabase(getContext());

}
}
```

I've also tried the same setup using ServiceTestCase and ApplicationTestCase, but I always get a 'null' context thus resulting in a NPE upon creating/opening my database. I'm trying this for several hours now, and seem to be completely stuck. I really don't know what I'm missing here, can anybody shed some light on me?

The database I'm using is actually read-only, so I don't need to install a separate one for the unit testing. I'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [RenamingDelegatingContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/RenamingDelegatingContext.html) in order to get a context you can use to open your database.

Add a RenamingDelegatingContext to your `setUp()` function as follows:

```
public class DatabaseTest extends AndroidTestCase {
Database database;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    RenamingDelegatingContext context
            = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");

    database = Database.getDatabase(context);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to call `database.close();` to close your database in the `tearDown()` function.

Reference: [This project on GitHub](https://github.com/bmarrdev/CountryRank/blob/master/countrydatabase/src/androidTest/java/com/hookedonplay/androidbycode/countrydatabase/DatabaseTestCase.java).

Comment: I seem to get access to a usable context with that, but my TestCase still can't access either the existing database nor the database file in my assets folder. When trying to access the assets, it throws NPE again.

Comment: It seems that the RenamingDelegatingContext is only able to access the database and not the application assets resources. I don't know a solution for this from within an AndroidTestCase.

Comment: I would be fine if it would be accessing my applications database, but it can't open it and so tries to copy a new one from my assets.